# Input a series number from keypad and print on LCD1602 using Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python

I am a newbie to Python. I am working with `Raspberry Pi 3` to program a control system for vending machine. I am done using use `python-opencv` to recognize the money. Now I want to input a series of number like `"99"` and print it on the `lcd 20x04 display`.

I am using the Python library:

- pad4pi-1.1.5
- rpi-lcd-0.0.2

Here the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import sys

sys.path.insert(1,"C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Raspberry_Pi/Library/pad4pi-1.1.5")
sys.path.insert(2,"C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Raspberry_Pi/Library/adafruit-circuitpython- 
pca9685-3.3.8")
sys.path.insert(3,"C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Raspberry_Pi/Library/rpi-lcd-0.0.2")

from signal import signal
from rpi_lcd import LCD
from pad4pi import rpi_gpio

lcd = LCD()
KEYPAD = [
    ["1", "2", "3", "A"],
    ["4", "5", "6", "B"],
    ["7", "8", "9", "C"],
    ["*", "0", "#", "D"]
]

# same as calling: factory.create_4_by_4_keypad, still we put here fyi:
ROW_PINS = [4,17,18,27]  # BCM numbering; Board numbering is: 7,8,10,11 (see pinout.xyz/)
COL_PINS = [22,23,24,25]  # BCM numbering; Board numbering is: 12,13,15,16 (see pinout.xyz/)
factory = rpi_gpio.KeypadFactory()

keypad = factory.create_keypad(keypad=KEYPAD, row_pins=ROW_PINS, col_pins=COL_PINS)
def printKey(key):
        print(key)
        global pressedkey
        pressedkey = str(key)

# store_key will be called each time a keypad button is pressed
keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(printKey)

while(True):
   time.sleep(5)
   lcd.clear()
```

I don't know to print the number on the lcd screen.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: first you should check documentation for `rpi_lcd`

Comment: maybe you should display it directly in `printKey` without `lcd.clear()` which removes all and you may not see displayed data .

Comment: I only found the command "lcd.text('Hello World!', 1)" in the library folder, how do I show the pressedkey on the LCD

Comment: I can't test it but simply in `printKey` run `lcd.text(str(key), 1)`. Eventually it may need to keep all numbers in global string and do `number = + str(key)` and `lcd.text(number, 1)`. And all without `lcd.clear()` in `while True` loop

Comment: I tried as you said but it just print nothing  TT

Comment: It just print the initial value of key ("key=0") TT